# Activerecord join in one-to-one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models, Word and Log. A Word has one Log, and a Log belongs to one Word. Not all Words have a Log.

How can I select all the Words that have a Log using Activerecord in Rails?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will perform a right join on logs which will remove all entries that do not have a log.

> Word.joins(:log).all

This is assuming you're using Rails 3 or later.

Comment: Whoops, :log is right P. I'm not too used to using has_one relationships.